# What does »bis zur Unsichtbarkeit verankert« mean?

Tags: phrase, german-to-english

The below paragraph comes from an [article](http://www.jetzt.de/rassismus/erfahrungen-mit-racial-profiling-in-deutschland) in *The Süddeutsche Zeitung* that discusses racism in Germany. A young Afro-German writes:

> Dass es Racial Profiling gibt, überrascht mich nicht. Es reiht sich ein in eine rassistische Tradition. Der Rassismus in unserer Gesellschaft ist strukturell und **bis zur Unsichtbarkeit verankert** und diese Art von Polizei-Kontrolle ist da nur ein Symptom. Es gab in den letzten Jahren vielleicht immer mehr Kritik daran, andererseits wird das Ganze von der Mehrheitsgesellschaft anerkannt und immer weiter normalisiert. Zum Vorgehen der Kölner Polizei an Silvester hört man ja jetzt auch immer wieder die Frage: 'Was hätte die Polizei denn machen sollen?'

*die Unsichtbarkeit* means *invisibility*. From the context, it seems that *bis zur Unsichtbarkeit verankert* means *deep-rooted*. But what did the author want to emphasize by using that phrase instead of something more common, like *tief verwurzelt*?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Bis zur Unsichtbarkeit verankert* indeed does not sound like a common expression. It seems to me the author wanted to express that racism is rooted that deep in society that it is virtually getting invisible, i.e., no one is noticing it or perceiving it consciously. The expression might be paraphrased as *society is blind to racism*.

In the case of *Rassismus ist tiefverwurzelt in der Gesellschaft*, people are aware of the issue but cannot easily solve it. In contrast, in the case of *Rassismus ist bis zur Unsichtbarkeit in der Gesellschaft verankert*, people are not even aware of the problem, which makes it even harder to solve it.